# Change the order of the Folder content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, modern-experience, folder

I have the below form that gets populated on selecting the action properties of the folder.

I want to change the order of the content type choices column to assign the second value to be the first value.

[image]

As mentioned, instead of having the folder content type as the first option I want the custom content type that I created under the Parent folder content to be the first value.

In addition, I found the custom content type in the advanced settings of the library but it's not reflecting the dropdown in the form:

[image]

Can please someone provide an example if possible to change the order and set the default value based on the above scenario?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, I could reproduce your issue and this is by design that if the custom content type inherits the Folder content type:

[image]

Comment: OP is trying to change the order of content type only. "Content Type" is not custom column in this case instead it is a SP default dropdown added on properties form when management of content type is enabled from advanced settings.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have updated my reply.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for your clarification and Julie for providing an example. Does that mean we can't change the order of the custom content type to be as the default option selected?

Comment: According to my test, just the folder parent content type is like this. I created a new custom content type based on Document, and this issue does not occur.